# Javascript - return most recent element for each name

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following data (cut down) from `crt.sh` for current SSL certificates.

```
[
    {
        "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
        "id": 4306577133,
        "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:02:05",
    },
    {
        "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
        "id": 4306565152,
        "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:00:00",
    },
    {
        "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net",
        "id": 4264152857,
        "not_after": "2021-06-22T02:01:45",
    },
    {
        "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
        "id": 4305553329,
        "not_after": "2021-06-29T16:15:11",
    },
    {
        "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net",
        "id": 3966036743,
        "not_after": "2021-04-22T12:18:00",
    }
]
```

I want an array of one entry for each domain that is the entry that will expire last (longest time to `not_after`).

Positionally it is *usually* the first one listed but not guaranteed.

```
[
    {
        "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
        "id": 4306577133,
        "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:02:05",
    },
    {
        "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net",
        "id": 4264152857,
        "not_after": "2021-06-22T02:01:45",
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would like to see your code.

Comment: Not got anywhere. I managed to group the data into the different domains with
```
result = res.reduce(function (r, a) {
        key = a.common_name || 'others';
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```
Not really found a good example to even get me started.

Comment: I can also sort the overall array - res2 = res.sort ( (a, b) => {
      return new Date(b.not_after) - new Date(a.not_after);
}); but then I need to extract the first record for each domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want an array of one entry for `each domain that is the entry that will expire last (longest time to *not_after*)`.

You can use `Array#reduce` to aggregate data with the highest performance - It just takes `O(n)` time complexity.

The main idea is to integrate all items, then do the trick like this

1. If does not exist item, then create a new one.
2. If exist item and `curr.not_after` is greater than `existng one`, then update `not_after`

```js
const items = [{"name_value": "unifi.borpin.net", "id": 4306577133, "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:02:05" },{"name_value": "unifi.borpin.net", "id": 4306565152, "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:00:00", }, { "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net","id": 4264152857,"not_after": "2021-06-22T02:01:45", },{"name_value": "unifi.borpin.net","id": 4305553329,"not_after": "2021-06-29T16:15:11",},{ "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net", "id": 3966036743, "not_after": "2021-04-22T12:18:00", }];

const result = items.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const existingItem = acc[curr.name_value];
  if(!existingItem) // if does not exist, then create new one.
    acc[curr.name_value] = curr;
  else if(new Date(existingItem.not_after) < new Date(curr.not_after)) // if curr.not_after is greater than exist one, then update not_after;
    existingItem.not_after = curr.not_after;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Yes it does - nice and concise. The explanation is excellent as well. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, does the line existingItem.not_after = curr.not_after; change the whole item or just the 'not_after' value?

Comment: Just `not_after` value, bro.

Comment: Ok so need to use existingItem = curr to replace the whole item?

Comment: It's up to you. In case that you want to change `id` value as well :)

Comment: Just want to take the whole item (in the real data there is more info). I ended up with `acc[curr.name_value] = curr;` in it's place so the if can probably be simplified as well. :)

Comment: It's the same. Bro. You can also adjust the assignment based on your needs :)

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do this using customize sort function and [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

> It would be easy to understand if we first sort the array with date in increasing order so that if we assign value to the object property then we don't need to check for any condition. Just assign the value to object property. The last one will be the `recent element`.

```js
const arr = [{
    name_value: "unifi.borpin.net",
    id: 4306577133,
    not_after: "2021-06-29T20:02:05",
  },
  {
    name_value: "unifi.borpin.net",
    id: 4306565152,
    not_after: "2021-06-29T20:00:00",
  },
  {
    name_value: "hassio.borpin.net",
    id: 4264152857,
    not_after: "2021-06-22T02:01:45",
  },
  {
    name_value: "unifi.borpin.net",
    id: 4305553329,
    not_after: "2021-06-29T16:15:11",
  },
  {
    name_value: "hassio.borpin.net",
    id: 3966036743,
    not_after: "2021-04-22T12:18:00",
  },
];

const obj = arr
  .sort((a, b) => {
    return new Date(a.not_after) - new Date(b.not_after);
  })
  .reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr.name_value] = curr;
    return acc;
  }, {});

const result = Object.values(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like below. Explanation is in comments.

```js
let data = [{
    "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
    "id": 4306577133,
    "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:02:05",
  },
  {
    "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
    "id": 4306565152,
    "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:00:00",
  },
  {
    "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net",
    "id": 4264152857,
    "not_after": "2021-06-22T02:01:45",
  },
  {
    "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
    "id": 4305553329,
    "not_after": "2021-06-29T16:15:11",
  },
  {
    "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net",
    "id": 3966036743,
    "not_after": "2021-04-22T12:18:00",
  }
];

let result = data.reduce((a, i) => {
  // get existing object for name_value 
  let obj = a.filter(x => x.name_value === i.name_value)[0];

  // if obj is null then create new object
  if (!obj) {
    // copy all values from item to object
    obj = { ...i
    };
    // push object into result array
    a.push(obj);
  }
  // else check if existing obj has smaller not_after then current item then replace id & not_after values
  else if (new Date(obj.not_after) < new Date(i.not_after)) {
    obj.id = i.id;
    obj.not_after = i.not_after;
  }

  // return resultant array
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be done in many ways.

For example: first, let's find the latest date for each domain. For this we use an object. After that, we transform the finished object into an array.

Note: Of course, for the correct date comparison, we need to convert your string values to dates.

In this case, the code will be something like this:

```
const inputArray = [{
  "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
  "id": 4306577133,
  "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:02:05",
},
  {
    "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
    "id": 4306565152,
    "not_after": "2021-06-29T20:00:00",
  },
  {
    "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net",
    "id": 4264152857,
    "not_after": "2021-06-22T02:01:45",
  },
  {
    "name_value": "unifi.borpin.net",
    "id": 4305553329,
    "not_after": "2021-06-29T16:15:11",
  },
  {
    "name_value": "hassio.borpin.net",
    "id": 3966036743,
    "not_after": "2021-04-22T12:18:00",
  }
]

const lastExpires = inputArray.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (
    !result[item.name_value] ||
    new Date(result[item.name_value].not_after) < new Date(item.not_after)
  ) {
    result[item.name_value] = item
  }

  return result
}, {})

const outputArray = Object.values(lastExpires)

console.log(JSON.stringify(outputArray, null, 4)
```